# I want the effect on my homepage whereby if I scroll downwards (even the slightest bit), a different page slides upwards to take its place

Tags: jquery

Any ideas how to get this effect. I'm new to this game. I tried mucking around with mouse wheel jquery but got no luck.The homepage as shown consists of a navigation bar across the top and a slider gallery. The contact page is the page I want to slide upwards. Thanks in advance. I hope Im clear.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Stack</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sss/sss.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sss/sss.min.js"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#slidemenu ul").hover(function(){
                  $(".item").toggle("slide", { direction: "right"  }, 400 );
              });
              }); 

              $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".menubutton").mouseover(function(){ 
                  $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "orange")
              })
                            .mouseout(function() { 
                  $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "white")
              });
              }); 

              $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".item").mouseover(function(){ 
                  $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "orange")
              })
                        .mouseout(function() { 
                  $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "white")
              });
              });

              $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".oneitem").mouseover(function(){ 
                  $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "orange")
              })
                           .mouseout(function() { 
                  $('.menubutton #line').css( "background-color", "white")
              });
              });

             jQuery(function($) {
             $('.slider').sss();
             });


    </script>
    <style>
                /* Standard Menu */
                  body {
                      margin: 0px;
                      padding: 0px;

                       }
                  header {
                      background-color: black;
                      height: 60px;
                      width: 100%;
                      position: fixed;
                      z-index: 100;
                       } /* This is our finished menu */
                 .blackbar {
                      height: 60px;
                      width: 100%;
                      background-color: black;
                      } /* As the menu is not fixed this keeps a black bar behind when the menu is at the veru top */
                  .logo img {
                      height: 40px; 
                      background-color:black; 
                      float: left;  
                      margin-top: 0px; 
                      padding:9px;
                      margin-left:  30px;
                      }
                  #navdiv li {
                      display: inline-block;
                      vertical-align: middle;
                      }
                  #navdiv a {
                      text-decoration: none;
                      color: white;
                      text-transform: uppercase;
                      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                      }
                  #navdiv a:active {
                      color:orange;
                      } /* Current Page Link Highlighted Orange */
                  #navdiv a:hover {
                      color: orange;
                      } /* Link Hovered Orange */
                  nav {
                      width: auto;
                      float: right;
                      word-spacing: 30px;
                      height: 60px;
                      min-width: 600px;
                      } /* This is the part of the menu with the page links laid out horizontally */
                  ul {
                      width: 600px;
                      letter-spacing: 0.14em;
                      margin-right: 20px;
                      margin-left: 20px;
                      padding-left: 0px;
                      }  /* List of Links to Pages */     
                /* Slider Menu */
                    #slidemenu {  /* The Slide In Menu */
                      height: 40px;
                      width: 105px;
                      padding: 0px;
                      margin: 0px;
                      float: right;
                      margin-right: 30px;
                      }
                    #slidemenu a {
                      text-decoration: none;
                      color: white;
                      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                      }
                    #slidemenu ul {
                      list-style-type: none; 
                      margin: 0px;
                      padding: 0px; 
                      }
                    #slidemenu ul .item {
                      display: none; 
                      right: 70px; 
                      }    /* Current slidemenu position */
                    .oneitem {  
                        display: block;
                        background-color: black;
                        width: 100px;
                        height: 19px;
                        text-align: center;
                        padding: 19px;            
                       }   /* This is already in place, jQuery doesnt need to bring this in */                 
                    .item {  
                        display: block;
                        z-index: 100;
                        background-color: black;
                        width: 100px;
                        height: 20px;
                        text-align: center;
                        padding: 19px;
                       }  /* jQuery brings this into play, by default it is overtaken by  (#menubutton ul .item) as this is more specific */ 
                /* MENU BUTTON */
                    .menubutton {
                        background-color: black;
                        visibility: visible;
                        margin-top: 10px;
                        margin-right: 20px; 
                        background-color: black;
                        position: absolute;
                        right: 20px;  
                       }
                    #line {
                        background-color: white;
                        width: 40px;
                        height: 5px;
                        margin: 6px;
                       }             
                /* RESIZING WINDOW ADJUSTMENTS */
                    @media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
                    nav{
                        display: none;
                    }
                    } /* Rids Navgation Links when screen is minimized */    
                    @media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
                    #slidemenu{
                         display: none;
                    }
                    } /* Rids Menu Button when at full-screen */ 
                    @media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
                    .logo img{
                        margin-left: 4px;
                    }
                    } /* Pulls Logo slightly left when screen is highly minimized to prevent Menu Bottom Colliding */ 
                    html, body, #container { height: 100%; }
                    body > #container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
                    #footer {
                     clear: both;
                     position: relative;
                     z-index: 10;
                     height: 130px;
                     margin-top: -3em;
                     background-color: black;
                     bottom: 0px;
                       overflow: hidden;

                     }
                    #content { padding-bottom: 3em; }
                    .box{
                      width: 15%;
                      height:124px;
                      display: inline-block;
                      min-width: 200px;
                    }
                    .box h1{
                      font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                      font-size: 20px;
                    }
                    #social img{
                      width: 60px;
                      height:60px;
                      margin:0px;
                      padding-bottom: 10px;
                    }
                    #social h1{
                        margin-bottom: 5px;
                      padding-left: 53px;
                    }
                    .container h1{
                font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
                z-index: 10;
                position: absolute;
                color: white;
                font-size: 184px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                text-align: center;
              }
              .outer {
                  display: table;
                  position: absolute;
                  height:15%;
                  width: 100%;
              }

              .middle {
                  display: table-cell;
                  vertical-align: middle;
              }

              .inner {
                  margin-left: auto;
                  margin-right: auto; 
              }
              .slider{
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;}






    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="overflow: hidden;">
        <header>
             <div class="logo">
                <img src="images/logo.png">
               </div>
             <div id="navdiv">
                <div id="slidemenu">
                  <ul>
                        <li class="menubutton">
                            <div id="line"></div>
                            <div id="line"></div>
                            <div id="line"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="oneitem" style="padding-bottom: 22px;"></li>
                        <li class="item" ><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="item"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                        <li class="item"><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                        <li class="item"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <nav>
                  <ul>
                     <li class="hide active"><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
                     <li class="hide"><a href='products.html'>Products</a></li>
                     <li class="hide"><a href='services.html'>Services</a></li>
                     <li class="hide"><a href='blog.html'>Blog</a></li>
                     <li class="hide"><a href='contact.html'>Contact</a></li>
                     <li class="hide">
                        <a class="fb_icon" href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">
                        <img src='images/facebook.png' onmouseover="this.src='images/facebookorange.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/facebook.png';"/></a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
                </nav>
              </div>
         </header>
                      <div style="background-color: black; width:100%; height:60px; visibility: hidden;"></div>







              <div class="container" style="">

              <div class="slider" style="min-width:800px;">
                  <img src="images/xxslider1.jpg">
                  <img src="images/xxslider2.jpg">
                  <img src="images/xxslider3.jpg">
                  </div>
                    <div class="outer">
                <div class="middle">
                <div class="inner">
                <div class="font" style="position: absolute; left: 50%;">
                <h1 style="position: relative; left: -50%;">Truss</h1>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>

              </div>

              <div style="width: 100%; height: 615px; background-color: white;"></div>










        <div id="footer">
            <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 705px;">                                                                    <!--To Centre Boxes-->
                <div class="box">                                                                                                      <!--Box-->
                    <h1 style="color: white; padding-top:40px; margin-left: 40px;">Get A Quote</h1>
                    <img src="images/black.jpg" style="width: 190px; height: 35px; ">   <!--Black Box under writing - keeps writing off bottom-->
                 </div>
              <div style="width: 40px; display: inline-block;"></div>                                                            <!--Space Div-->
              <div class="box" id="social">                                                                                            <!--Box-->
                        <h1 style="color: white;">Follow Us</h1>
                        <div style="width: 90px; height: 2px; background-color: white; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-left: 51px"></div>  <!--Line-->
                        <div style="width: 128px; margin-left: 33px;">                                     <!-- Containing div for two circles-->
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/facebookfooter.png"></a>
                            <img src="images/twitterfooter.png">
                         </div>
               </div>
              <div style="width: 40px; display: inline-block"></div>                                                             <!--Space Div-->
              <div class="box">                                                                                                        <!--Box-->
                <img src="images/ce.png" style="height: 30px; margin-left: 75px; ">
                <img src="images/black.jpg" style="width: 190px; height: 40px; ">       <!--Black Box under writing - keeps writing off bottom-->
               </div>
             </div>
         </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you referring to something like [this](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/) ?

Comment: Yes, very similar. How to I incorporate the scroll in to that. And how do I make it so that it goes to my other page.